Mouse click on a Bunifu Drop Down in a panel does not work
I used click - mouse up - mouse down event for this drop down to call a function whenever user clicks on this DropDown(ComboBox).
But by clicking on this Combobox nither mouse click nor other events are triggered. The dropdown is in a bunifupanel. I believe the panel is suppressing these events!
`
    private void PortsDropDown_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    GetPortsInfo();
    }

    private void PortsDropDown_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    GetPortsInfo();
    }

    private void PortsDropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    GetPortsInfo();
    }

`
But by clicking on this Combobox nither mouse click nor other events are triggered. The dropdown is in a bunifupanel. I believe the panel is suppressing these events! However panel_Click event works fine.
I searched this through stackoverflow and I found a few similar topics. But, they didn't help.
